# Function template argument with any return type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the below templated deletor class which I use with unique_ptr to delete C types.

```
template<typename T, void (*DeletorFunc)(T*)>
struct CTypeDeletor
{
  void operator()(T* ptr)
  {
    DeletorFunc(ptr);
  }
};

int main(void)
{
  typedef unique_ptr<CType, CTypeDeletor<CType, CType_free>> CTypePtr;
  CTypePtr ctype(CType_new());
  // ctype will be deleted when we return from main
}
```

Well, this works as long as CType_free's return type is 'void'. But if the dfree function's return type is not 'void' then I couldn't use the CTypeDeletor.

Is there a way I can make the CTypeDeletor more generic so that I can use free function with any return type?

Comment: How will providing a return type different than `void` be helpful?

Comment: @RSahu `fclose`, for example, doesn't return `void`.

Comment: If all `CTypeDeletor` does is wrapping a function pointer, why not just use the function pointer's type directly as the deleter type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your existing solution more generic this way:

```
template<typename T, typename RetType, RetType (*DeletorFunc)(T*)>
struct CTypeDeletor
{
  RetType operator()(T* ptr)
  {
    return DeletorFunc(ptr);
  }
};
```

However, this is needlessly convoluted since you can simply do

```
int main(void)
{
  typedef unique_ptr<CType, decltype(&CType_free)> CTypePtr;
  CTypePtr ctype(CType_new(), &CType_free);
}
```

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr),

> Deleter must be FunctionObject or lvalue reference to a FunctionObject or lvalue reference to function, callable with an argument of type unique_ptr::pointer.

Comment: Assuming that `CType_free` is a function, `unique_ptr<CType, CType_free>` won't compile. You need a `decltype`.